# Passing Arguments to GraphQL with Next.JS and Apollo

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, graphql, next.js

A lot of this is very new to me since I have been a PHP developer for so long.

I am having a couple of issues that I know are easy to fix. I just have limited experience and am learning.

1. I cannot seem to pass the argument $token_id.  I am using next JS, and I just want to take the number on the [id].js page, and pass it as the token ID.
2. I can't seem to get data from traitType, which is an object named "traits" which has an array of objects inside of it.

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {


  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: 'http://localhost:3000/api/graphql',
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  });

  const token_id = String(context.params.id)
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
          query myQuery($token_id: String!) {
            getData(token_id: $token_id) {
                token_id
                name

            }
        }
    `
  },{ variables: { token_id } });

    props: {
      data: data,
    }

}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [], //indicates that no page needs be created at build time
    fallback: 'blocking' //indicates the type of fallback
  }
}
```

My Type Definition

```
    type Blah {
        token_id: String
        name: String
        #traits: [traitType] #TODO: returns nothing since data is array

    }

  type traitType {
      trait_type: String
       value: String

   }
```

I have to hard code the token

```
     getData(token_id: "6") {
        token_id
        name
  
        traits {
            trait_type
        }
}
```

I have tried several variations in the graphql query

```
query getDataQuery($token_id: String! = "6") {
    getData(token_id: $token_id) {
```

Returns Null on traits, and $token id is null, and nothing is found

```
    "traits": [
        {
          "trait_type": null,
      "value": null
        }
      ],
```

And my JSON from mongo db is an array with an object.

```
    "traits" : [
        {
            "trait_type" : "birthday", 
            "value" : 1627423029.0, 
     
        }

]
```

I can post more than just fragments of code.  Sorry for the formatting.